# Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a$ belongs to G. Will $H = \{a^{2n}:n\in Z\}$ be a subgroup of $G$? Won't $G$ have to be commutative?

Comment: What's the definition of a subgroup generated by $a^2$?

Comment: yes $H=<a^2>$ a subgroup of G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e\in H$ since $a^{2\cdot0}=a^{0}=e$ by definition.

The inverse of $a^{2n}$ is $a^{-2n}\in H$ since $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
then so is $-n$

And finally

$$
a^{2n}\cdot a^{2m}=a^{2(n+m)}\in H
$$

Answer (score 1):

The commutativity of $G$ is not required. Clearly the identity $e \in H$. If $a=e$, then $H=\{e\}$ is the trivial subgroup. Otherwise choose $x,y\in H$. Say $x=a^{2n}$ and $y=a^{2m}$, where $n$ and $m$ are integers. Then $xy^{-1}=a^{2(n-m)}\in H$. Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.